# The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null' StreamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, nullable

I have recently upgraded my flutter to the latest version  and I am getting all the null safety errors.

```dart
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('restaurants')
  .doc(partnerId)
  .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
}
final restaurant = snapshot.data;
startTime = restaurant['startTime'].toDate();
endTime = restaurant['endTime'].toDate();
```

I am getting the following error when I assign restaurant[''] to any variable.

> The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver
> can be 'null'.

If I do this - `restaurant!['endTime'].toDate();`, new error comes

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object'. Try defining
> the operator '[]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try casting the `snapshot.data` to whatever your stream returns.

example:
if your stream returns a `Map`, here is your code:

```
StreamBuilder(
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
  .collection('restaurants')
  .doc(partnerId)
  .snapshots(),
builder: (context, snapshot) {
if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Center(
    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
  );
}

// dont forget to assume that your stream may
// have an error, or dont return data.
if(!snapshot.hasData) return Container();

final restaurant = snapshot.data as Map;
startTime = restaurant['startTime'].toDate();
endTime = restaurant['endTime'].toDate();
```

Comment: That worked, thanks! Also, I am getting a similar error on snapshot.data.docs - final documents = snapshot.data!.docs;

Comment: well, you can use the same method, `final documents = snapshot.data!.docs as Map;`, but reaplace `Map` with whatever the docs' datatype is

Answer (score 0):

`snapshot.data` is an `AsyncSnapshot`. You have to do the following:
`Map<String, dynamic> restaurant = snapshot.data.data()` if you're getting a single document.